# Trying to understand what I'm doing wrong - Iterative sum of linked list Y86

Tags: assembly, y86

I'm doing this for a class lab and I'm not getting where I'm going wrong. The program works if I suffix all my instructions with l instead of q ( eg - andl instead of andq , rrmovl instead of rrmovq ) but not with the q. I'd really appreciate some pointer on what I'm doing wrong.

```
   .pos 0
    init:   irmovq  Stack, %rsp     # Set up stack pointer
    rrmovq  %rsp,%rbp       # Set up base pointer
    irmovq  ele1,%rax
    pushq   %rax
    call    sum_list        # Execute main program
    halt                    # Terminate program


   # Sample linked list
    .align 8
    ele1:   .quad 0x00a
    .quad ele2
    ele2:   .quad 0x0b0
    .quad ele3
    ele3:   .quad 0xc00
    .quad 0

  # int sum_list(list_ptr ls)
    sum_list:   pushq   %rbp
        rrmovq  %rsp,%rbp
        xorq    %rax,%rax       # val = 0
        mrmovq  8(%rbp),%rdx    # edx = ls
        andq    %rdx,%rdx       # Set condition codes
        je      End
    Loop:       mrmovq  (%rdx),%rcx     # ecx = ls->val
        addq    %rcx,%rax       # val += ls->val
        mrmovq  4(%rdx),%rdx    # ls = ls->next ------ tried +8 insetead of 4 also
        andq    %rdx,%rdx       # Set condition codes
        jne     Loop
    End:        rrmovq  %rbp,%rsp
        popq    %rbp
        nop                     # makes sure stop in 31 steps
        ret

 # The stack starts here and grows to lower addresses
    .pos 0x100
```

Stack:

Comment: `q` is 64-bit operand size, `l` is 32-bit operand-size.  Your list nodes have two qword members, though (pointer and value), so `q` should be correct.  `4(%rdx)` looks wrong: you're reading 4 bytes from the middle of the value?  (Or 8 bytes with `q` operand-size).  `l` operand-size should work (as long as you still use offsets of `8`) because the pointers and integers are all small so truncating them to 32 bits doesn't change their value.

Comment: Is there a `y86` debugger that can single-step your code?  Use it to look at values in registers.

Comment: I tried https://xsznix.github.io/js-y86/ and my code works when it's all l suffix, not when it's q suffix. One  problem I've noticed is if I just stop after putting the 1st element into rax , I get 0x0a00000000000000 instead of 0xa ( possible left shift happening on its own )

Comment: Most likely that's from doing an 8-byte load that overlaps two struct members.  The low 32 bits of `%rcx` are 0 (from the high half of a pointer), and the high 32 bits have the `0xa` from `ele1`

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry but any idea on how to fix that problem . I can't use l suffixes. Again sorry for being a noob at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting your function args incorrectly:  `mrmovq  8(%rbp),%rdx` puts your function's return address into `%rdx`.

That happens to be a few bytes before `ele1`, which explains the offset-load that's creating the "shifted" value you see without just crashing.  IDK how you don't crash right after that, though.

---

Your pointer arg is placed on the stack by the caller with `push %rax`.  After that, `call` pushes a return address (8 bytes).

Inside your function, `push %rbp` decrements `%rsp` by another 8 bytes before you copy it to `%rbp`.  Thus the pointer arg pushed by your caller is at `16(%rsp)`, which is also `16(%rbp)`.

```
mrmovq  16(%rbp),%rdx    # rdx = ls
```

When debugging, always try to test your assumptions.  The hard part is sometimes figuring out *what* you're assuming, because it's often the thing you didn't even consider as a possible problem that bites you.  (e.g. in this case, getting the function args.)

---

It would be easier to pass function args in registers, like 64-bit x86 code does.  e.g. first arg in `%rdi`, second in `%rsi` is what the x86-64 System V calling convention uses.  But if you're "supposed to" pass args on the stack like 32-bit x86 calling conventions, remember that each `push` is 8 bytes wide.

OTOH, it's important to know how to use the stack, and keep track of what call / push / pop are doing to it.

Comment: @BonnyMahajan: that's fine, it's better to ask and learn the reasoning than to blindly use the solution.  I counted the modifications to `%rsp` after the `push %rax` in the caller that put the arg on the stack:  `call` and `push %rbp` both push 8-byte values onto the stack.  See also the paragraph in my answer right before the `mrmovq  16(%rbp),%rdx` code block.  Is it hard to understand?  Could I phrase that better so it would be easier to understand for other beginners?

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)